# JSON Web Token Support For The JVM does include impl, api and jackson?

Tags: java, jwt, token

I need to use a dependency JWT in java for secure token authentication in my Java application.
My question is. Do I need to use all 3 dependencies individual as :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Or I can use a single one who includes all of them :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And why do I need to specify the scope at run-time when

> Notice the above dependency declarations all have only one compile-time dependency and the rest are declared as runtime dependencies.

> This is because JJWT is designed so you only depend on the APIs that are explicitly designed for you to use in your applications and all other internal implementation details - that can change without warning - are relegated to runtime-only dependencies. This is an extremely important point if you want to ensure stable JJWT usage and upgrades over time:

> **JJWT guarantees semantic versioning compatibility for all of its artifacts except the `jjwt-impl` .jar. No such guarantee is made for the `jjwt-impl` .jar and internal changes in that .jar can happen at any time. Never add the `jjwt-impl` .jar to your project with `compile` scope - always declare it with `runtime` scope.**

[Understanding JJWT Dependencies](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#understanding-jjwt-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the JJWT version 0.10.0, both the `io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api` and `io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl` were packaged as a single artifact, `io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt`.

With release JJWT version 0.10.0, these have been split into two different artifcats.

from release notes of [JJWT Release Notes, version 0.10.0:](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0100)

> BACKWARDS-COMPATIBILITY NOTICE:
>
> JJWT's new modular design utilizes distinctions between compile and
> runtime dependencies to ensure you only depend on the public APIs that
> are safe to use in your application. All internal/private
> implementation classes have been moved to a new jjwt-impl runtime
> dependency.
>
> If you depended on any internal implementation classes in the past,
> you have two choices:
>
> Refactor your code to use the public-only API classes and interfaces
> in the jjwt-api .jar. Any functionality you might have used in the
> internal implementation should be available via newer cleaner
> interfaces and helper classes in that .jar.
>
> Specify the new jjwt-impl .jar not as a runtime dependency but as a
> compile dependency. This would make your upgrade to JJWT 0.10.0 fully
> backwards compatible, but you do so at your own risk. JJWT will make
> NO semantic version compatibility guarantees in the jjwt-impl .jar
> moving forward. Semantic versioning will be very carefully adhered to
> in all other JJWT dependencies however.